# Как в Win10 получить сервисную информацию от диска, подключенного через переходник USB to SATA

Tags: windows

Необходимо получить всю сервисную информацию диска, подключенного через переходник USB to SATA к ПК с ОС WIN10. Подразумевается получение: имени, s/n, распределения LBA, наличие АТА пароля и прочее. Думаю надо использовать ATA команды, но АТА команды через переходник не проходят или...? Кто может помочь: добро пожаловать. Так же возможен фриланс по написанию консольного приложения.

Comment: Возможно зависит от конкретного переходника, но через имеющиеся у меня USB-SATA переходики связанные с ATA программы (hdparm и пр.) вроде нормально работают

Comment: hdparm линукс? Вроде она есть и на вин10, но в урезанном виде

Comment: Может `smartmontools` поможет?

Comment: неа, smartmontools тут бесполезен. PassMark OSForensics - неплохо себя зарекомендовала. Какие еще есть решения?